# Computing $F_{12}$ when $F(x,y)=f(x,xy);F(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I've a question as follows:

> Compute $F_{12}$ when $F(x,y)=f(x,xy);F(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))$

I think it to be an application of implicit function theorem . but don't know how to apply,
kindly help with this...

Comment: With $F_{12}$ do you mean $F_{12} \equiv \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y}$?

Comment: @Winther yes,exactly..